# Simple Linux shred script error

Tags: bash

I have an ultra-simple script that houses the Linux program shred, and it contains the parameters that have always worked from the command line (bash). Specifically 'shred -uzn 35'

The script, named D, has execute permissions set.

When I run the script, bash prints an error:

```
$ D some_file_to_delete
shred: missing file operand
```

I realize that the solution to the problem is probably as simple as the program itself. Please help?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The error "missing file operand" was due to the fact that the script was not set to take arguments, such as via "$@". Also, as stated in the accepted answer, I agree that an alias makes total sense for such a scenario (much more sense than, say, a script somewhere in $PATH).

Comment: Can you post your script as well?

Comment: The file contains only the command `shred -uzn 35`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a script, not an alias, you need to pass the arguments through

```
shred -uzn 35 "$@"
```

In this case, however, I suggest you do make it an alias. In your `.bashrc` file, add this:

```
alias D='shred -uzn 35'
```

Comment: I would define a function instead: `D () { shred -uzn 35 "$@"; }`. There's rarely a reason to define an alias instead of a function.

Comment: @chepner I disagree. This is just running a command with some default arguments, which is basically what an alias is made for.

Comment: I'd even go so far as to say don't bother with a function when an alias will suffice. Why do you dislike aliases?

Comment: I see people constantly trying to use aliases in situations they won't work--with arguments, in non-interactive shells--and having problems when a command is shadowed unknowingly by an alias (which, granted, can be a problem with functions as well, but not as often since it's much easier to shadow a command with an alias). Except for extreme edge cases (mostly related to command-line completion as far as I can tell) which most people aren't even aware of, they don't accomplish anything a function cannot. Even the `bash` documentation says functions are preferred over aliases.

Comment: I'm glad to see that there is some conversation opening up here. This was my first post to this site and I'm glad to have at least found a curious audience.

I have attained basic functionality with the program, by the way.

Now I am wondering: Why have the preference of a function or an alias over a script in a situation as simple as this?

Comment: @j'est Aliases are nothing but simple textual replacement, functions are somewhat more complex (can take arguments, multiple statements); both of those live in memory and so are faster and more efficient. A script has to be read from disk and parsed every time. See [my answer about this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/11750) on [Unix.SE].